# Malicious app that misuses Stack Overflow trademarks is up on the Google Play Store

Tags: support, android-app, security, trademark

Today I came across an Android app which is misusing Stack Overflow's logo and name in the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=apps.secondart.stackoverflow).

[image]

Users have reported regarding the security issues they have faced and the developer has given the same reply for almost all the queries.

The logo and name of the app can make someone believe it is legitimate. I have flagged it as inappropriate, but no action has been taken so far.

Staff and Moderators, kindly look into it.

Comment: This is up to Google to remove, if they don't care to have malicious apps in their store, very little SE can do.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 SE can file a legal trademark complaint against the app and get it taken down.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 I think SE can file a DMCA notice as they infringe on the copyrighted logo.

Comment: In the meanwhile we can all report the app as "impersonating" or something along those lines.

Comment: @Luuklag The Stack Overflow logo doesn't meet the threshold of originality (in the US at least) and is therefore in the public domain. But the screenshots in the listing *do* seem to contain content copyrighted by SE.

Comment: Here’s another one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sanson.stackexchange

Comment: @EmilJeřábek no, this one is fine. It clearly says "A UI app for StackOverflow users" and has no ads, developer does not profit from it. The one reported in this question try to imposter itself as the official SO app, and the developer makes money from ads inside.

Comment: Google tests applications before offering them on their website, each browser must be approved to access Google login, if you have notifications turned on you get one when a previously unused browser is authenticated, these are expected: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2812853?hl=en#zippy=%2Chow-privacy-alerts-work --- A trademark misuse and a privacy concern are two different things, there's nothing to support the second.

Comment: @Rob It's fairly obvious this is malware stealing credentials. On Android phones, you have to be logged in with a Google account. You don't provide your password to the apps. Legitimate ones use Google's services to authenticate you. Hell, even on my iPhone I can use the Google account for my email to "login with Google" and not provide my password an additional time.

Comment: @V2Blast why not make it status-completed? The app appears to have been deleted since.

Comment: Similar on MSO (in the same time frame): *[Is this app a legitimate Stack Overflow app?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413342/)*

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yeah, please do not install this app.  Our Trust and Safety team is aware and is following up on this.

Comment: I hope the Google team will review the other apps by this developer as well. They have one impersonating BBC World that seems very similar.

Comment: @ColleenV- I would hope so as well, but obviously I cant commit to that for them, as I dont work there. :-)

Comment: How's this going?

Comment: Hi @Ollie, once it's reported to Google, I don't expect to hear anything further.  They don't tend to communicate beyond that.

Comment: That application is now removed from the Google Play Store. Thank you all!

Comment: @Ak. One down, many more to go:  https://apkplz.net/app/apps.secondart.stackoverflow  https://apktada.com/app/apps.secondart.stackoverflow https://apkzz.com/tag/apps-secondart-stackoverflow/ --- Search for: "apps.secondart.stackoverflow" for a partial list.

Comment: @Philippe Take a look at this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sanson.stackexchange

Comment: @RandomPerson yeah, another scammer trying to make easy money. Good catch!

Answer (score 32):

[image: flag app]

Enough of these, and hopefully someone in Google will notice and nuke this out of orbit.

Comment: Can this be done in desktop?

Comment: @RandomPerson tried now, and no it's not available on PC, sadly.

Comment: It's possible: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2853570 :)

Comment: @RandomPerson no it is not. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Sorry! Here you go: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/takedown